# $\sup(A\setminus\{z\}) = \sup(A)$ other direction and generalisation.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let A be a nonempty set, such that $z\in A$ and $\sup(A) \not \in A$

> (a) $\sup(A \setminus \{z\}) = \sup(A)$
>
> (b) generalise  this to  $\sup(A \setminus \{z_1 z_2 z_3 \dots z_n\})=\sup(A)$

**Let us denote $A$ with $z$ removed by $B$**

For the first part I know that removing a point from $A$ can only really lower the supremum, because we might remove the right "end point", so the only possibility for $\sup(B)$ is that $\sup(B) \leq \sup(A)$, we can also see this via this formal argument:

Let $y \in A $, but $y \neq z$, then we have that $y \leq \sup (B)$, but certainly we have that $y\in B$ so now this is an upper bound for $B$, since $\sup(B)$ is the lowest of bounds for $B$, we have:
$$ \sup(B) \leq \sup(A)$$

**I fail so see the other direction, the problem is if we start out with an arbitrary element of $B$ is that we cannot say anything about $z$, at least I don't see this.**

For (b) we simply solve this by induction on $n$,  here is a rough sketch, I think this approach is fine, but correct me if I am wrong:

Our **base case** will hold by question (a), our **inductive hypothesis** generalises this for arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{N} $ to $A \setminus \{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k\}$ and then for our **inductive step** we  first consider $A \setminus \{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k \}=C $ this is useful notation to make things shorter.

We can now write that: $\sup(C\setminus\{z_{k+1}\})=\sup(C)$ by question $(a)$,

We now use our inductive hypothesis ($\sup(C)=\sup(A)$) and state that: $$\sup(A\setminus\{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_k,z_{k+1}\})= \sup(C\setminus\{z_{k+1}\})=\sup(C)=\sup(A)$$
By the principle of mathematical induction the desired relation holds. $\square$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sup(B)<\sup(A)$. Then, take $x\in A$ such that $\sup(B)<x<\sup(A)$ (We can do it by definition of $\sup$ and because $\sup(A)\notin A$). Then, we have that $x\notin B$ hence $x$ must be $z$. But it is impossible because it would imply that $z=\sup(A)$. Then, we have that $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$.

Comment: clever, just suppose it does not and we get a contradiction. I often forget contradiction as an approach - thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I feel with every bit of steering in the right direction I'm becoming better at analysis, thank you :)

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo You are welcome.